# How do I connect the RIGHT way from One Server SQL to another and make updates?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, root, crm

I have two servers that I want to integrate between, Both are using MySQL server.
I would like to be able to run a Query from one Server to the other server and search the DB using a filter that I have and apply the changes while checking the DB on the other server.

The scenario is like this:

> ***Server One*:** MySQL server with Database of Clients with a Status field that is *member* and I want to update the customer details in the CRM server by the FILTER BY STATUS=MEMBER. `Select * From Customers where status=Member` (or somthing like that). the Idea is that I would be able to CONNECT the CRM Server and run the task on it's Database. can that be doen? and How can I do that?

AND

> ***Server Two* (CRM):** has its MySQL server as well and a database of Members with all connections. I would be happy to be able to connect the CRM server with all the info I got from the other server using the Filter that I mention above and update the members database accordingly.

How can I do that? I need to connect the Server using the root@hostname user with all privileges that I will be able to manipulate any Database that I will chose to work on. And update it on will.

Please assist me with the above integration and how do I do that? What is the RIGHT way to connect from one server MySQL server using a query with Filtering to another Server's SQL database and update it?

Please assist.
Thanks
Arye

Comment: I would recommend using an ETL tool.

Comment: Thanks. can you please recommend which one I should be using? and how can i find the right one?

Comment: My tool of choice has been Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services